# MVC clear cache after certain time of day

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have a controller action with `OutputCache` attribute, looks like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 14400)] // 4 hours
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = // fill out model

    return View(model);
}
```

So I cache the action for 4 hours. What I want to do is regardless of how long into these 4 hours, if it's after `10pm` at night, I want to reset/clear the cache. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime expireWeights = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999); Cache.Insert("CacheItemName", list, null, expireWeights, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

You can set an absoluteExpiration time on the Cache object, which is a DateTime.

You can also combine an absoluteExpiration with a SqlCacheDependency.

Regarding the issue of it not pulling the new data when the cache expires: you can wire up a CacheItemRemovedCallback to receive notification of when it expires, and refresh the cache at that time.

OR
in model

```
public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

controller :-

```
[NoCache]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Home()
 {
     ////////...
}
```

you have to set the expiry by using below line code : DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1350). 
Or else (1350*60)--> duration and controller will have to go through your file every time the action call it

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 81000, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //reset cache
            User u = new User();
            return Content(u.getCountryDetails());
            //send notification 
        }
```

or 
You can add a Header to your HttpContext.Response in your controller

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("refresh", "1350; url=" + Url.Action("Index"));
```

there are many ways you can cache, its up to your comfortably.

Hope helps you.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work. I don't see where I would place the first line of code.

I like the Attribute way, assuming that is a separate solution? Only thing is I can't  get it to reset at a certain time of day. Not sure I was clear about that. I want the cache to expire at a 4 hour interval. With one exception, when the clock is after 10pm, I want to expire the cache and start caching at a 4 hour interval again.

Comment: you can create the class and able to access any where in your application. You are using in same solution? if not you keep in same solution.

Comment: Ok. What part of your code tells the cache to start again? When I try this it just stops the cache completely after certain time.

Answer (score 0):

The way you think about the problem makes it too complicated. If you want to invalidate at 10 PM and cache 4 hours you get always the same times for a cache, so a new cache is started at 10 PM, 2 AM, 6 AM etc.

I'd think you can implement it like this:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(custom))
        {
            switch (custom)
            {
                case "4HoursStart10":
                    var baseDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
                    return "CacheKey-" + (baseDate.Hour / 4);
                    break;
            }
        }    
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

This will give you a new cachekey every 4 hours:

- CacheKey-4 for 9/7/2017 6:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-4 for 9/7/2017 7:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-4 for 9/7/2017 8:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-4 for 9/7/2017 9:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-5 for 9/7/2017 10:00:40 PM <- new at 10 PM!
- CacheKey-5 for 9/7/2017 11:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-5 for 9/8/2017 12:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-5 for 9/8/2017 1:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-0 for 9/8/2017 2:00:40 AM <- new because its been 4 hours
- CacheKey-0 for 9/8/2017 3:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-0 for 9/8/2017 4:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-0 for 9/8/2017 5:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-1 for 9/8/2017 6:00:40 AM <- new because its been 4 hours
- CacheKey-1 for 9/8/2017 7:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-1 for 9/8/2017 8:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-1 for 9/8/2017 9:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-2 for 9/8/2017 10:00:40 AM <- new because its been 4 hours
- CacheKey-2 for 9/8/2017 11:00:40 AM
- CacheKey-2 for 9/8/2017 12:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-2 for 9/8/2017 1:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-3 for 9/8/2017 2:00:40 PM <- new because its been 4 hours
- CacheKey-3 for 9/8/2017 3:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-3 for 9/8/2017 4:00:40 PM
- CacheKey-3 for 9/8/2017 5:00:40 PM